# HTTP 500 error with Simple.OData.Client when authenticating

Tags: basic-authentication

I keep getting a 500 error when trying to create the ODataClient and passing in ODataSettings with new NetworkCredentials(username, password). Anyone have any examples of creating this service with Basic Authentication?

Comment: I just found your question. Issues like this is better to register at the GitHub project page. Are you using version 2.0 (recently released) or the earlier one?

Answer (score 2):

I enabled basic authentication for a sample OData Web site, and then I was able to access it using Simple.OData.Client and the following code:

```
var settings = new ODataClientSettings();
settings.UrlBase = "http://localhost/ProductService/odata";
settings.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Tester", "tester123");
var client = new ODataClient(settings);
```

If it doesn't work for you I suggest you check if it works when you disable basic authentication and open the site for anonymous access. If it still doesn't work, then the problem is with something else. Otherwise let me know what platform and Simple.OData.Client version you are using (I tested on .NET 4.0, .NET 4.5 and Simple.OData.Client v.2.0.0).